# How to force hibernate not to save and data updates on session closing?

Tags: java, hibernate, orm

For example I have entity extracted from hibernate session `User user = session.getById(12); user.setName('new_name') reject request` After this code block I do not want to store updates to user and use it purely as Data Bean but also I do not want to detach it from session because I want lazy loading. For modification i want to use methods save, saveOrUpdate. Is it possible to said hibernate not to automatically update all modified fields of session objects?

Answer (score 1):

FLUSHMODE.MANUAL only flushes if you specifically say to, I believe.

Comment: Does it guarantee that methods like merge, save will store actual data to database?

Comment: Is it possible to configure SessionFactory to always create Manual flushed sessions?

Comment: @yura - No. You have to FLUSH. Alternatively use FlushMode.Commit() and commit(). Otherwise no flushes occur. SessionFactory does not have a default for this mode AFAIK, of course you could provide a SessionFactoryHolder object that returned wrapped Sessions with your default.

Answer (score 0):

You can use stateless sessions. They don't do any dirty checking and corresponding auto-magic updates. Obviously, you would lose session cache (you can keep track of your objects yourself) and batched inserts/deletes/updates.

Comment: No, I don't like to lose session cahce and performance. Moreover I want to increase performance by not doing dirty check on flush.